# AssertEquals tests in Java doesn't work for Pair objects

Tags: java, key-value, assert, assertion

Does somebody know why this test fails? These are 2 identical objects with content inside, if I add the `toString` method after each `Pair` the test will pass. I tried to override the `Equals` method from the `Object` class but still nothing. Any help will be great, thanks

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(key, value);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}
```

[Pair Class Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6WWD.png) 
[Error assertEquals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqJkf.png) 
[They are actual identical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGiLt.png)

Comment: You say you tried to override the `equals` method in your `Pair` class.  I don't see that in the code you've provided.  You need to do that, because that's what `assertEquals` actually calls.

Comment: Okay, i'll update screenshot now

Comment: No, just paste the code into the question.  Don't mess around with screenshots.  They're hard for us to test.

Comment: `super.equals` in this case is just `Object.equals` which compares whether the objects are literally identical, as in the *exact* same object. You need to define what makes the objects equal inside that method. For all intents and purposes, you didn't override the method at all since it just calls the super.

Comment: Ye, I actually tried to change the code inside method equals and still nothing
`public boolean equals(Pair<K, V> pair) {
return this.key == pair.key && 
this.value == pair.value ; }
`

Comment: Don't use `==`.  That only returns `true` if the two sides are the exact same object, which may or may not be the case for the `key` and `value` fields in your objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your override of `equals` doesn't do anything - it just calls the implementation that you overrode.  In other words, it has no effect.

You need to override `equals` in a way that does the comparison that you need.  In other words, your `equals` needs to

- check that the `Object` being compared to is also a `Pair`,
- call `equals` for the two `key` fields,
- call `equals` for the two `value` fields.

If any of these conditions fail, your `equals` should return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;
    return key.equals(pair.key) && value.equals(pair.value);
}
```

This code resolved problem :)

Comment: Note that this implementation is broken, in that it crashes (and as per the contract of `equals`, that means this code is broken) if the value of key or value is `null`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).